# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userProfile' available as request attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, exception

I've encountered the folowing exception while I was trying to implement my first spring+hibernate web app:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userProfile' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    ...
```

UserController.java:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserProfileService userProfileService;

    public UserController(){

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("userProfile") UserProfile userProfile, BindingResult result, Map model){

        userProfileService.addUserProfile(userProfile);

        return "redirect:/login";
    }
    ...
}
```

UserProfile.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_PROFILE")
public class UserProfile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    //sets and gets
}
```

index.jsp

```
<form:form method="post" action="add" commandName="userProfile">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="userName"><spring:message code="label.username" /></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="password"><spring:message code="label.password" /></form:label></td>
            <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.adduser" />"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't noticed that I have to implement method for form creation which will provide instance of UserProfile. I've added 2 methods and now everything works fine.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "redirect:/index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createRegisterForm(Map<String, Object> model){
    model.put("userprofile", new UserProfile());
    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `modelAttribute="userProfile"` to the `<form:form>` tag.

```
<form:form method="post" action="add" commandName="userProfile" modelAttribute="userProfile">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding BindingResult as a method parameter next to  `@ModelAttribute("userProfile") UserProfile userProfile`

Spring looks for BindingResult  parameter after each @ModelAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to your controller should fix it

```
model.addAttribute(new UserProfile());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ModelAttribute("userProfile")
public UserProfile getProfile(){
    return new UserProfile();
}
```

```
<form:form method="post" action="add" modelAttribute="userProfile">
```

Comment: It'd be great if you could add a few words to your answer explaining how it works.

Comment: Spring looking instance(UserProfile) for push all data from form, in this case we create this instance and in 'modelAttribute="userProfile"' form parameter relate to our method with annotation(@ModelAttribute("userProfile")). It work for me in my case It's User and Projects)))