# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'search' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation

I'm new to Spring MVC and I have an error with a form validation and I don't know why.

This is the model:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Search implements Serializable {

@Size(max = 20)
private String userInput;

@Size(max = 10)
private String ascending;

@Size(max = 10)
private String descending;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fromDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date toDate;

@Size(max=100)
private String genres;

public String getGenres() {
    return genres;
}

public void setGenres(String genres) {
    this.genres = genres;
}

public String getUserInput() {
    return userInput;
}

public void setUserInput(String userInput) {
    this.userInput = userInput;
}

public Date getFromDate() {
    return fromDate;
}

public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
}

public Date getToDate() {
    return toDate;
}

public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
    this.toDate = toDate;
}

}
```

Here is the form:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>



<sf:form action="/newSearch" method="post" modelAttribute="search">

<sf:input path="userInput" type="text" class="input_style" id="userInput" /> 

<button class="search_button"><img class="search_icon"       src="resources/img/search/search_icon.png" /></button>

<sf:select id="genres" path="genres"  multiple="multiple">

</sf:select>

<sf:input id="fromDate" path="fromDate" />  

<sf:input id="toDate" path="toDate" type="text" />

<sf:input id="ascending" path="ascending" type="radio" checked="checked" />

<sf:input id="descending" path="descending" type="radio" />

</sf:form>
```

and here is the Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getSearch(@Valid Search search, BindingResult result, Model m) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "home";
    }
    System.out.println("----------------Search--------------------");
    System.out.println(search.getGenres());
    System.out.println(search.getUserInput());
    return "search";
}
```

The error is: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'search' available as request attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userProfile' available as request attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554795/neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-userprofile-availa)

Answer (score 0):

Add `@ModelAttribute("search")` before `@Valid` making the method's signature look like

`public String getSearch(@ModelAttribute("search") @Valid Search search, BindingResult result, Model m)`

Also try

`<sf:form action="/newSearch" method="post" commandName="search">`

instead of

`<sf:form action="/newSearch" method="post" modelAttribute="search">`